# What's the word for starting a contest?

Tags: word-request

What's the word for starting a contest? Not really starting, but financing it and being legally liable to award the winner. I can't think of a verb for that.

Example:

> The company organized and ___ the contest.

Comment: What's wrong with *started*?

Comment: something like sponsoring ?

Answer (score -2):

The verb *sponsor* seems best in your case:

[image]